# this error : g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Tags: scons

I encountered this error:

> g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

When I'm following the instructions given by the site http://gem5.org for building **`gem5`** on Ubuntu Linux by using this command :

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: What version of g++ and scons are you using?  Were there any compiler warnings before the compiler error?

Comment: Try to gear down compiler's optimization level in the build system.

Answer (score 2):

upgrade to the latest release of a still supported major version of gcc (as of writing, 5,6, and 7), and try again. and if it crashes on the newest version, file a [bugreport.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) what you're experiencing is a compiler bug. luckily, in my experience, compiling gcc on ubuntu is a breeze. run `sudo apt-get build-dep gcc` , and basically follow this guide https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC  (protip: speed up the compilation by using `make -j $(nproc)` - compiling it will take quite some time! )